# How to use HRESULT condition check in C++

Tags: c++, winapi, hresult

```
HRESULT hr = S_OK; //initialization`
if (int i == 5)
{
    hr = 1; //Is it correct usage?  
}
if (hr == 1)
    cout<<"The value of i is 5";
```

As I always heard `HRESULT` output in strings like `E_TIMEOUT` etc. whether it's correct to use a number like I've used.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12852626/why-is-hresult-0-for-success

Comment: That's not the answer to my question. My question is different. I can not use SUCCCED or FAILED case because i know it's getting failed but there are multiple codes for failure and i've to use particular failure code.

Please read my question again.

Comment: Don't use specific hardcoded hr values.  Use standard error codes as defined in `<WinError.h>` or  using `MAKE_HRESULT` to create your own error codes.

Comment: HRESULT is Windows specific. Do not make *any assumptions*, use what the SDK says. It's FAILED or SUCCEEDED or compare it with known HRESULT values.

Comment: The code does not even compile, so please provide a proper example.

Answer (score 3):

The main question here is what are you using the `HRESULT` for?

You can obviously assign any value to an `HRESULT` but then why not just use an `int`?

`HRESULT`s are used as a way to communicate success or failure of function calls. Usually an `HRESULT` is either `S_OK` (0) or an error (negative numbers). `S_FALSE` (1, not a failure but not success either) is more rarely used.

When used with COM or .NET the caller usually only checks if the function succeeded or failed. By default when marshaling a function that returns an `HRESULT` .NET's marshaller will turn the function into a `void` function, throwing an exception if the result is negative and discarding the result if it's non-negative.

If this is the case for your code then there's no point in giving a specific positive value. If you're not using this for interoperability you probably shouldn't be using an `HRESULT` at all.

Comment: Well said @Motti

Answer (score 2):

An HRESULT of `0` or `S_OK` is the standard "success" code.  Whereas `1` is S_FALSE, which means, "success, but I didn't exactly do you what you asked because it was probably already done".

Standard pattern is something closer to this:

```
HRESULT hr = S_OK //initialization


if (int i == 5)
{
    hr = S_OK;    
}
else
{
    hr = E_INVALIDARG;  // Or any E_ error code
}

if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    cout<<"The value of i is 5";
}
else if (hr == E_INVALIDARG)
{
    // handle specific error
}
else
{
   // handle all other errors generically
}
```

Comment: In the context of WIN32 and HRESULT, that is not a "standard pattern".

Answer (score 2):

Basically, everything is inside '<winerror.h>'. But, I have this feeling, that might be not a popular answer.

**The Context**

HRESULT is a handle (value of type long) returned from Win32, COM and other functions in the vast ocean of Windows SDK. What and how is packed in that handle is explained in `<winerror.h>`

I might dare to think there is one fact about Win32 of great use to C++ developers.

**Win32 is written in C**

Thus there are no C++ exceptions. Ditto HRESULT is your friend. There are "special exceptions" called SEH (Structured Exceptions Handling). And they are "inbuilt" into the Windows. Even MS STL uses SEH when c++ exceptions are switched off (gasp!). But that was not part of the question.

The usage looks very simple:

```cpp
HRESULT hr ;
ULONG  ansi_size_  ;
        hr = DiscpUnicodeToAnsiSize(L"Look Ma, I am doing WIN32!", &ansi_size_ );

        if ( FAILED(hr) ) {
              //  there was some error
              //  what exactly has happened?
              HRESULT facility = HRESULT_FACILITY(hr);
              HRESULT severity = HRESULT_SEVERITY(hr);
              // we can for example look for a particular facility 
              if ( facility  == FACILITY_MSMQ) 
              {
                 // hey, just what is MSMQ ?!
                 // let see the code part
                 HRESULT code = HRESULT_CODE(hr);
              }
        }
```

`<winerror.h>` is (currently) 62238 lines long. Feel free to browse it and you will find a lot of useful nuggets.

Wikipedia [article on HRESULT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HRESULT) is actually short and to the point.

Win32 is now several decades old. Inevitably there are dusty corners. But HRESULT will stay "forever" and in active development.

As it happens Windows Error Codes Protocol Revision 20 (gasp) [has been released just yesterday](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-erref/1bc92ddf-b79e-413c-bbaa-99a5281a6c90)!

**But that is C!?**

There have been few official projects (also released) to "encapsulate" HRESULT and COM into C++ types. MFC, ATL ... My favourite is [Compiler COM Support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/compiler-com-support?view=msvc-160), and in particular, the [_com_error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/com-error-class?view=msvc-160) class.

I hope this has helped ...